# Google apps Script won't record submissions

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

Below is a program that I put together, from research and some of my own adding, and I'm having many issues with it. The `record_submission` function isn't working properly. Every time I test with someone submitting their name, it won't properly record the information which then effects the next function, the notification function which I wrote to automatically send me an email once someone submits a response. Would appreciate some help.

Attached are the images of the Google spreadsheet that I want updated whenever someone submits a response as well as the face of the website people will be submitting information from. The record function is supposed to do that. It's giving me a error saying that the variable isn't properly assigned or something of the sort and the notification email doesn't work properly either.

[image: Google sheets image]

[image: Website image]

This is the whole JavaScript code:

```
 //* This function handles the get request from the web browsers */
 function doGet(e)
 { 
     //return form.html as the response return
     HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
 }

 // Record all the information entered into the form into a Google Sheet.
 function record_submission(form)
 {
     Logger.log(form);
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dQQ1b3NjeYgVEOLIaSNB-XCZwAPAQr6C85Wdqj-sBM8");
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // Assume first sheet collects responses

     // Build a row of data with timestamp + posted response
     var row = [ new Date(), // Timestamp 
                 form.last_name[0], // last name
               ]; // Make sure we are the only people adding rows to the spreadsheet
     var lock = LockService.getPublicLock(); // Wait for up to 30 seconds for other processes to finish. 
     var locked = lock.tryLock(30000);
     if (locked)
     {
         // Save response to spreadsheet 
         var rowNum = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
        sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

        // Release the lock so that other processes can continue.
        lock.releaseLock(); 
        var result = "Response Recorded: \n 
 "+row.join('\n  ');
    }
    else
    {
        // Failed to get lock
        result =
 "System busy, please try again.";
    }
    // Report result of POST, in plain text
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

 // Send an email to yourself notifying you when someone made a submission.
function notification(last_name, assignment_name)
{
   var subject = "New Submission"; MailApp.sendEmail("*my email*@gmail.com",
 subject, 'New submission received from ' + last_name + ' for the
 assignment: ' + assignment_name );
}

 /* This function will process the form when the submit button is
 clicked */
 function uploadFiles(form)
 {
     try
     {
         notification('test','test'); //Retrieve a reference to the folder in Google Drive 
         var folder_name = "Test_Folder"
         var folder =
 DriveApp.getFolderById("0By69oDzO6OluTm9KNGVuaUZZdE0");

         // Create a new folder if the folder does not exist 
         if (!folder)
         {
             folder = folder.createFolder(folder_name);
         }

         //Get the file uploaded through the form as a blob
         var blob = form.myFile;
         var file = folder.createFile(blob);

         //Set the file description as the name of the uploader
         file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.LastName);     

         //Set the file name as the name of the uploader
         file.setName(form.LastName + "_" + form.AssignmentName); 

         //This function should store the information of the submission to a Google Sheet

         record_submission(form);

         //This function should notify you when there has been a submission 
         notification(form.LastName, form.AssignmentName);

         // Return the download URL of the file once its on Google Drive
         return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUr1();
   }
   catch(error)
   { 
       // If there's an error, show the error mesage   return
       error.toString();
   }
}
```

### This is the whole HTML code

> ## File Upload
>
> ```
> <!--User inputs --> 
> <h4>First name</h4> 
> <input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder = "Type your first name.." > 
>
>
> <h4> Last Name </h4> 
> <input type="text" name = "LastName" placeholder="Your last name...">
>
> <h4> Assignment Name </h4>
> <input type="text" name="Course" placeholder="Course number"> 
>
> <!--File upload--> 
> <h4>Upload</h4> 
> <input type="file" id="file" name="myFile" style="display:block; margin: 20px;" value = "myFile"> 
>
> <!-- Submit button --> 
> <input type="submit" value="Submit" 
>     onclick= "this.value='Uploading..';
>          google.script.run.withsuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
>          .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
>          return false;">
>            </form>    <div id="output">  </div>     <script>
>  function fileUploaded(status) { 
>      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none'; 
>      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
>      }
>
>
>      /*check to see if the user's first name input is empty. 
>      If it is empty alert the user to fill in his/her first name */ 
>
>
>      </script>
>
>      <style> 
>           input {display:block; margin: 20px; }
>           </style>
>
>  </body> </html>
> ```

Comment: I did that several times and the issue persists.

Comment: I tried several times obviously. Hence me having to ask this question in depth on here.

Comment: Just curious, what makes you think the 'last_name' property of the form object is an array? Maybe I'm missing something, but the following notation looks a bit strange to me 'form.last_name[0]', especially since your code defines the property as 'LastName' in HTML

Comment: Wouldnt I have to make it an array since that's how it'll record the responses for that subject? I'm not too sure, this is roughly my first attempt. Several loose ends

Comment: Each form submission event generates its own form object that looks like the standard JavaScript object where keys are the values for of the 'name' attribute and values are the actual values entered by the user. If you have <input name='lastName'> and the user entered 'John', then posting the form would return the following result {lastName: 'John'}. The result is not shared across multiple submissions

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. This logic just goes over my head because i have yet to learn javascript properly. This is an assignment due for a class project and the only code i've learned is C++. So javascript isn't exactly my forte rn. As for the submission recording, you're saying that javascript doesn't need to be told what to do in every sense? Like, it works hand in hand with the HTML file?

Comment: Roughly speaking, yes. It does so because JavaScript runs inside the browser. The browser is basically a platform that abstracts away a ton of things to make your life easier, including adding event listeners where needed etc.

Comment: I see I see. Do you know of any sample scripts i can look at to mimic this outcome? I set up a google forms and connected it to a google sheets and it works the exact way that I want it to. I just want to see the record_submission script that's used so i can finally get this script up and running.

Comment: You can easily fix your 'record_submit' function by simply removing the array reference.  Think of each form submission event as creating another instance of a class in strongly-typed languages. You can then easily push these object values to the row array pass it as parameter to the appendRow() method. 1) <input name="lastname"> 2) var arr = [form.lastname] 2) sheet.appendRow(arr)

Comment: I'll try that right now and i'll let you know what happens.

Comment: I can remove the arrays but the issue that making this go over my head is what would replace them. Like how will javascript take in the submissions that need to be stored. I've actually never used the appendRow() method.

Comment: JavaScript does not store anything. As soon as your code finishes executing or you reload the page, all variables go out of scope and get destroyed. It's your responsibility to record and persist data. In this case, you already use Google spreadsheet as a database, so why would you need anything beyond that? appendRow() is the Google Apps Script method defined for the Sheet object. You can look it up in GAS docs

Comment: I see what you're saying know. Beforehand i thought javascript would need to have been the middle man, in a sense, to carry over the data taken from the submission page. I'm gonna research the appendRow() method. This is great. I really appreciate you're help. In case i try this and run into some issues, if i comment on this post, will it notify you? I really appreciate your help man!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g7h70b this is the error that im getting. am i doing something incorrect using the appendrow() method?

Comment: I don't understand why you keep referencing  'form.last_name' with the underscore while your html clearly has the 'name' attribute defined as 'LastName' for that input field. Also, this syntax is completely incorrect var sheet = ss.appendRow(arr)()[0];  1) You are calling the method on entire spreadsheet - must be sheet instead  2) appendRow() returns instance of Sheet object - why are you executing it like a function by adding parenthesis? Of course, the sheet is not an array, so [0] is wrong as well. It only takes a few seconds to look up correct examples in GAS docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your 'input' tags are not wrapped in a 'form' tag, so what gets passed to the 'onclick' function as parameter might actually be the entire <body> tag. Are your inputs nested inside the <form> tag? If not, then this.parentNode would be the entire body of the HTML document.

I put together the quick example illustrating the entire process. On the client side, we are listening for the form submit event. Once the event fires, we call the server-side function via google.script.run and pass the form object to that function as an argument.

Code.gs

```
function onOpen(){

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

ui.showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
  .setTitle('siderbar'));

}


function logFormObject(form){

Logger.log(form); //check the logs by pressing Ctrl + Return
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // get the 1st sheet in the spreadsheet
sheet.appendRow([form.name, form.lastName, form.age]); //create row contents array from the form object and pass it to the appendRow() method


}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">

      Name <br>  
      <input name="name" /> <br>
      Last Name: <br>  
      <input name="lastName" /> <br>
      Age: <br>  
      <input name="age" /> <br>

      <input type="submit" value="send">

    </form>
    <script>

      window.onload = function(){

        var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

          event.preventDefault(); //prevents redirect to another page
          google.script.run.logFormObject(this); // calling the server function in Code.gs

        }); 


      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g7musj I played around with your code and it goes through properly after i play it in GAS. But every time I enter in a submission it doesn't get recorded properly.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g7mwy3 and even if put the variable FirstName or LastName it doesn't recognize it and calls it undefined even though it's already labeled as such in the HTML form

Comment: It's undefined because you attempt to run the function manually in the editor.  If you entered the values in the form, you wouldn't even see the red error message. In this case, the error response from the server is displayed in browser's console.

Comment: Okay I'll try that. Is there anything else you see that I should adjust?

Comment: StackOverflow is the place to ask specific questions - it is not intended for line-by-line debugging of your code. That said, here's the working example that you can copy and examine https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JVmo6OWiA4c8Mejd1wksazG9LOeYpvCbBSyIV5MkIzo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The script created under my account can't be authorized automatically for your account even if I share the file with you. You MUST open the Script Editor and run functions manually to trigger Google authorization flow for your account